# Issue with pushing certain layers (received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable)

Tags: python, docker, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to push an image to an acr repo by following the instructions on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-prepare-acr

After repeatedly having pushed to the repo do I keep getting the following error (503 Service Unavailable):

```
4e3c4bdd8bfe: Layer already exists
cdae82220b48: Layer already exists
d3425a455cb5: Layer already exists
8fbb024a9e28: Layer already exists
3bb921ccd79d: Pushing [==============================================>    ]  10.24MB/10.99MB
f0d12f622fa6: Layer already exists
b7fe4d3535be: Retrying in 20 seconds
7663e4e44dcd: Layer already exists
00db256c021d: Layer already exists
626941e0d298: Layer already exists
03d5e23e1dd0: Layer already exists
40683d611cd5: Layer already exists
received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable
```

The error is always for two specific layers, with status "Retrying" and "Pushing".

Any help in understanding the issue is welcome.

I inspected the problematic layers with `dive` (since I'm on MacOS)

```
Cmp   Size  Command
56 MB  RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux;         wget -O python.tar.xz "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION%%[a-z]*}/Python-$PYT ...
11 MB  RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux;         wget -O get-pip.py "$PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL";     echo "$PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256 *get-pip.py" | sha25...
```

The layers which fail to be pushed look like this (identified by their digest sha256 hash. (The full command is not displayed since it is cut of by *dive*.)

**Problematic layer 1:**

```
Tags:   (unavailable)
Id:     8cf7d0e0050abc76db256a5e312baf1ee8a3cacdf60e185e96ac676e9868b2a4
Digest: sha256:b7fe4d3535be9e73191e41a0d212629840faedea9bf9482219a46b47ee1f8618
Command:
RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux;         wget -O python.tar.xz "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION%%[a-z]*}/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.ta
```

**Problematic layer 2:**

```
Tags:   (unavailable)
Id:     164ddaa51a1726d2c5ee755241be4790dbcf7475dbf9b14ad844ebc780b4a9d5
Digest: sha256:3bb921ccd79db85deeec8666f06ef210581d1cfacb0e1a7b1db5028e1a69520b
Command:
RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux;         wget -O get-pip.py "$PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL";     echo "$PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256 *get-pip.py" | sha256sum -c -;
```

It looks like both these layers are coming from the [python:bullseye](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/331890ef059fae05f84c652520b78c340526dc71/3.11/bullseye/Dockerfile) image.

I fast glance at the different layers singles out the two problematic ones in such a way that these are both doing RUN commands with `wget`. Not sure why that would be an issue though.